Sharing kernel keyring between systemd services
I am working with kernel keyring (e4crypt tool stores its keys there).
For some reason systemd doesn't share kernel keyrings between services. Service A launches a script that creates a key and then it's nowhere to be found inside service B (running keyctl show there doesn't show the key).
I found there is a KeyringMode=shared option, so I added User=root and KeyringMode=shared to both A and B service files. Unfortunately, this had no effect. The keyring is till empty when service B launches.

Which keyring are you adding keys to? The session keyring, the user keyring, something else?

@grawity_u1686, the session one. E4crypt uses it by default. My guess is that the issue might have something to do with possession or access rights.

If you make the service run keyctl show, does it show the same ID of its session keyring?

@grawity_u1686, service A gives 275477083 --alswrv  0  0  keyring: _ses and service B gives 922937713 --alswrv  100000 100000  keyring: _ses. This is without User=root and KeyringMode=shared since adding this to every service file isn't feasible.

I've tried running keyctl setperm $KEY_ID 0x3f3f3f3f (giving everyone all writes to the key) but to no avail.

Okay, but whether it's feasible (or necessary) to add it to every service is a different question – can you test with the option enabled in services A and B, to actually make sure it has an effect? (Because it is necessary, given that it defaults to '=private'.)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78778611/share-keys-between-sessions-of-kernel-keyring - gave you some more information there.
